# Converting backend json response to Ember store expected format

Tags: ember.js

I am pretty new to ember and trying to do some POC's to fit our existing applications.

Using ember **1.13.12** and ember data **1.13.15**

I have two models,

**company.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    employee: DS.hasMany('employee',{async:true}),
});
```

**employee.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({

    name: DS.attr('string'),
    alias: DS.attr('string')
});
```

The serializers extend the JSONSerializer and sets the primarykey for both models and the option embedded always for employee model.

Backend json response for /employee/7, - this results in error - Ember.A(...) map not a function

```
{
    "name": "abc"
    "employee": {
        "employeeId": 7,
        "name": "employee7",
        "alias": "e7"
    }
}
```

Backend json response for /employees - this gets pushed to the ember store without issues

```
{
    "name": "abc"
    "employee": [
        {
            "employeeId": 1,
            "name": "employee1",
            "alias": "e1"
        },
        {
            "employeeId": 7,
            "name": "employee7",
            "alias": "e7"
        }
    ]
}
```

With the above response I faced two issues,

- **Not having an 'id' for the 'company' model to push to the store** (Workaround ended up changing the backend response to have an 'id')
- **When I try getting a single employee say employee/7/ the json response from backend does not return as an array** (Workaround added one of the normalize hook and added a line payload.employee = [payload.employee] and it worked)

Is there a way I can get past the above issues without changing the backend response and workarounds.

Comment: I'm curious, why are you using an older version of Ember?

Comment: You can [define the primary key of the model](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_ids).

Comment: I tried with version ember 2.4.2 and the request to /employees failed with error data is undefined. And for the primary key, I am looking for a way to generate one and use that to push the record.

Comment: Have you tried looking at customizing the Serializer to convert the response to appropriate format? https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_customizing-serializers

Comment: I have got the existing code working with ember 2.4.2 version but the issues mentioned above persists, i went through the serializers and only thing i came up was payload.employee = [payload.employee] and nothing on generating an id. Also, with 2.4.2 i have to close the ember inspector everytime after i change from console to Ember or Network, other the application doesnt get loaded with a deprecated message, 'The initialize method of application initializer ember-inspector-booter should accept only one argument'